# Align and cases not recognized when using acmsmall.cls

Tags: equations, align

I have switched from using acmsmall to using acmart.  A lot of my confusion was caused by things failing one way if I had \usepackage{amsmath} or did not.  Errors were very mysterious as I had a lot of \usepackage commands from copying from an old document that worked.  Using acmart.cls, and no other \usepackage commands has it all working.  Thanks, Fred

Comment: Are you loading the `amsmath` package?

Comment: `align` is not defined by default in an `article` class document either.

Comment: The class `acmsmall` has been replaced by `acmart`. As far as I know, ACM conferences and journals should use the latter.

Comment: Your code compiles without error if I replace the `acmsmall` document class with `acmart`.

Comment: Incidentally, writing `1/2 i` is somewhat ambiguous: does it mean `(1/2)i`, or does it mean `1/(2i)`. I suspect it's supposed to mean the latter. Don't hesitate to use parentheses to get rid of such ambiguities.

Comment: I just downloaded acmart.cls.  If I don't use amsmath.sty, then I get

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has solved the problem